# AmazonAutoScalingAsync client not seeing ASGs (Auto scaling Groups)

Tags: aws-sdk-java-2.0

I've set up AmazonAutoScalingAsync client as well as many others but I'm unable to retrieve the existing ASGs.

> ```
> BasicSessionCredentials sessionCredentials =
>       new BasicSessionCredentials(
>           credentials.getAccessKeyId(),
>           credentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
>           credentials.getSessionToken());
> ```

```
  // Assume role
  AWSSecurityTokenService sts_client_mfa =
      AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
          .withRegion(region)
          .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(sessionCredentials))
          .build();

  AssumeRoleRequest request =
      new AssumeRoleRequest()
          .withRoleSessionName("proserv-" + username)
          .withRoleArn("myarn");
  AssumeRoleResult response = sts_client_mfa.assumeRole(request);
```

Then I build the auto-scaling client as follows:

> ```
>   autoScalingClient =
>         AmazonAutoScalingAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
>             .withCredentials(
>                 new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
>                     new BasicSessionCredentials(
>                         response.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId(),
>                         response.getCredentials().getSecretAccessKey(),
>                         response.getCredentials().getSessionToken())))
>             .withRegion(region)
>             .build();
> ```

These are the same steps I do from the AWS console but can't see the same results on the Java code.

```
getAutoScalingClient()
        .describeAutoScalingGroupsAsync()
        .get()
        .getAutoScalingGroups()
        .forEach(
            group -> {
              System.out.println(group);
            });

    getAutoScalingClient()
        .describeAutoScalingInstancesAsync()
        .get()
        .getAutoScalingInstances()
        .forEach(
            entry -> {
              System.out.println(entry);
            });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. I was using the wrong region. After switching to the correct region it displayed as expected.